# java.lang.ThreadDeath error message when running code

Tags: java, cryptography, java-threads

So I have written a Java Program (Which I have attached the code for below) for a cryptographic cipher I designed (based on the SPN cipher but with a few modifications). Anyways, when I run my program, the code instantly stops and I receive a java.lang.ThreadDeath error. I have tried even adding a print statement to the very beginning (as in first line) of my main method (so it was the first thing processed by my program), but I had no luck, Java stopped before my print statement could even run.

Here is my code:

```
package SSPN;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main throws IOException{
public static final int NUM_ROUNDS = 1;
public static final File f = new File("sBoxes.txt");
//Need better comments!!
//For each character, prints out a binary string of length 7. Does zero - padding!
public static String[] plaintextToCharacterBinarySequence(String plaintext)
{
    //Getting int values
    int[] charRepresentations = new int[plaintext.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < charRepresentations.length; i++)
    {
        char ch = plaintext.charAt(i);
        int asciiValue = (int)ch;
        charRepresentations[i] = asciiValue;
    }
    String[] binValues = new String[charRepresentations.length];
    System.out.print("Binary values are: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < binValues.length; i++)
    {
        String str = Integer.toBinaryString(charRepresentations[i]);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
        if (str.length() !=7)       
        {
            int DIFF =  7 - str.length();    //As it is an Ascii Value, must be less than length 7
            for (int j = 7; j > (7 - DIFF); j--)
            {
                sb.insert(0,"0");
            }
        }
        str = sb.toString();
        binValues[i] = str;
        System.out.print(binValues[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();

    return binValues;
}

public static String binarySequenceToString(String[] sequence)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i =0; i < sequence.length; i++)
    {
        int val = Integer.parseInt(sequence[i], 2);
        char ch = (char) val;
        sb.append(ch);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

/*We define an instance of the affine cipher (for extra security), with a = length of message,b = ascii value of 1st character.
m = 128. Then, we convert the output to (zero-padded) 7-bit binary number, and store the result as the output of a hash
table (where the input binary number is the key)*/
public static HashMap<String, String> defineandStoreSBoxes(File f, int lengthOfMessage, int firstAsciiValue) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
    HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap <String, String>();
    String currentSBox;
    while ((currentSBox = br.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        int  base10Val = Integer.parseInt(currentSBox, 2);
        int encryptedOutput = lengthOfMessage * base10Val + firstAsciiValue; //(LIMITATION: Without modding by 128, encryptedOutput Cannot exceed Integer.MAX_VALUE)
        String binOutput = Integer.toBinaryString(encryptedOutput);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(binOutput);
        if (binOutput.length() !=7)       
        {
            int DIFF =  7 - binOutput.length();    //As it is an Ascii Value, must be less than length 7
            for (int j = 7; j > (7 - DIFF); j--)
            {
                sb.insert(0,"0");
            }
        }
        binOutput = sb.toString();
        hm.put(currentSBox, binOutput);
    }
    br.close();
    return hm;
}

//This method performs bitwise XOR on each block of the plaintext and the bits of the round key (which are the same size)
public static String[] xorSubkey(String[] currentText, String roundKey )
{
    for (int i =0; i < roundKey.length(); i++)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String binStr = currentText[i];
        for (int j =0; j < 7; j++)
        {
            int chCurrent = Character.getNumericValue(binStr.charAt(j));   //Either 0 or 1
            int chKey = Character.getNumericValue(roundKey.charAt((1 * 7)+ j)); 
            if (chCurrent == chKey)
            {
                sb.append("0");
            }
            else
            {
                sb.append("1");
            }
        }
        currentText[i] = sb.toString();
    }
    return currentText;
}

public static String[] sBoxSubstitution(String[] currentText, HashMap <String,String> hm)
{
    for (int i =0; i < currentText.length; i++)
    {
        String val = hm.get(currentText[i]);
        currentText[i] = val;
    }
    return currentText;
}

public static String[] linTransform(String[] currentText)
{   
    int shift =  currentText.length % 7; 
    for (int i =0; i < currentText.length; i++)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(currentText[i]);
        String sub = currentText[i].substring(shift, 7);
        sb.insert(0, sub);
        sb.delete(currentText[i].length(), currentText[i].length() + (7 - shift));
        currentText[i] = sb.toString();
    }
    return currentText;
}

public static String[] encrypt(String plaintext, String[] roundKeys) throws IOException
{
    String[] binaryText = plaintextToCharacterBinarySequence(plaintext);
    HashMap<String, String> hm = defineandStoreSBoxes(f, plaintext.length(), (int) plaintext.charAt(0));
    String[] xoredSequence, substitutedSequence,transformedSequence = null;
    //The first Num_Rounds -1 Rounds
    for (int i =0; i < NUM_ROUNDS -1; i++)
    {
        xoredSequence = xorSubkey(binaryText, roundKeys[i]);
        substitutedSequence = sBoxSubstitution(xoredSequence, hm);
        transformedSequence = linTransform(substitutedSequence);
    }
    // the final round
    xoredSequence = xorSubkey(transformedSequence, roundKeys[roundKeys.length - 2]);    //Make sure this isnt null
    substitutedSequence = sBoxSubstitution(xoredSequence, hm);
    //Final xor Subkeying
    String[] ciphertext = xorSubkey(substitutedSequence, roundKeys[roundKeys.length - 1]);    //Make sure this isnt null
    return ciphertext;

}

//DECRYPTING
public static String[] decrypt(String textToDecrypt, String[] roundKeys) throws IOException
{
    String[] bitCiphertext = plaintextToCharacterBinarySequence(textToDecrypt);
    HashMap<String, String> hm= defineandStoreSBoxes(f,textToDecrypt.length(), (int)textToDecrypt.charAt(0) );          //Make sure this is reversed 
    String[] xoredSequence, substitutedSequence,transformedSequence = null;
    //Decrypting final ciphertext
    String[] finalXOR = xorSubkey(bitCiphertext, roundKeys[roundKeys.length - 1]);
    // Final round
    substitutedSequence = reverseSBox(finalXOR, hm);
    xoredSequence = xorSubkey(substitutedSequence, roundKeys[roundKeys.length - 2]);
    //Reversing the loop order
    for (int i = NUM_ROUNDS -1;  i >= 0; i--)
    {
        transformedSequence = reverseLinTransform(substitutedSequence);
        substitutedSequence = reverseSBox(transformedSequence, hm);
        xoredSequence = xorSubkey(substitutedSequence, roundKeys[i]);
    }
    String[] plaintext = xoredSequence;
    return plaintext;
}
 public static String[] reverseSBox(String[] value, HashMap <String, String> hm)
{
    for (int i =0; i < value.length; i++)
    {    
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : hm.entrySet()) 
        {
            if (value[i].equals(entry.getValue())) //Because s-boxes are bijective
            {
                value[i] = entry.getKey();
            }
        }
    }
    return value;
}
 public static String[] reverseLinTransform(String[] value)
{
    int shift =  7 - (value.length %7); 
    for (int i =0; i < value.length; i++)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(value[i]);
        String sub = value[i].substring(shift, 7);
        sb.insert(0, sub);
        sb.delete(value[i].length(), value[i].length() + (7 - shift));
        value[i] = sb.toString();
    }
    return value;
}

public static boolean isGoodRoundKey(String key, int plainTextLength)
{
    if (plainTextLength == key.length() && key.length() % 7 ==0 && isBinary(key) ==true)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    } 
}

public static boolean isBinary(String number)
{
    for (int i =0; i < number.length(); i++)
    {
        char c = number.charAt(i);
        if (c != '0' && c != '1')  
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    System.out.println("Inside main");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));   //Buffered reader will read in plaintext, and round keys
    System.out.print("Enter the text that you would like to encrypt: ");
    String plaintext = br.readLine();
    int numChars = plaintext.length();//The total number of characters that make up this string
    String[] roundKeys = new String[NUM_ROUNDS + 1];//Each box will have 7 bits
    System.out.println("The cipher will encrypt for "+ NUM_ROUNDS + "rounds, so you will need to enter some round keys. ");
    System.out.println("Each round key must be a sequence of zeroes and ones, and must be exactly seven times the length of the plaintext string");

    //Storing all the round keys in the array!
    for (int i =0; i <= NUM_ROUNDS; i++)
    {
        if (i ==0)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter the round key for the 1st round: ");
        }
        else if (i ==1)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter the round key for the 2nd round: ");
        }
        else if (i ==2)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter the round key for the 3rd round: ");
        }
        else if (i == NUM_ROUNDS)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter the round key that will be XORed at the very end of all the rounds ");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print("Enter the round key for the " + i+1 + "th round: ");
        }
        roundKeys[i] = br.readLine();
        System.out.println();

        /*Check to make sure the round key that is passed in is valid. If it is not, an error message will be printed to the user,
        prompting them to enter a valid round key. This will loop indefinitely until a valid round key is entered.
        */
        if (isGoodRoundKey(roundKeys[i],plaintext.length() ) !=true)
        {
            boolean isValid = false;
            while(isValid == false)
            {
                System.out.println("ERROR: the key you entered is not a valid key for this cipher.");
                System.out.println("Please enter another key: ");
                String new_key = br.readLine();
                if (isGoodRoundKey(new_key, plaintext.length()) ==true)
                {
                    roundKeys[i] = new_key;
                    isValid = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    br.close();
    String[] bitCiphertext = encrypt(plaintext, roundKeys);
    String ciphertext = binarySequenceToString(bitCiphertext);
    System.out.println("The encryption of " + plaintext + " is: "+ ciphertext);
    String[] discoveredBitPlaintext = decrypt(ciphertext, roundKeys);
    String discoveredPlaintext = binarySequenceToString(bitCiphertext);
    System.out.println("The encryption of " + ciphertext + " is: " + discoveredPlaintext);//Reverse order of round Keys
}
```

}

Comment: What's in your classpath? This is likely due to a deprecated piece of code being included, as "An instance of `ThreadDeath` is thrown in the victim thread when the (deprecated) `Thread.stop()` method is invoked.`" Alternatively you might be using a deprecated IDE environment, but I think an included library file is more likely.

Comment: My class path is C:\ProgramData\Oracle\java\javapath, and it contains the following files: java.exe (version 9.0.4), javaw.exe (version 9.0.4) and javaws.exe (version 12.0.4). My IDE is Netbeans 8.2, with Java 8.141, which is a bit older. Do you think that could be the problem?

Comment: I would certainly try and run your code on a modern runtime and without IDE. I think it is likely that your code is ok but something else is not.